# Replacing PNG images with transparent background in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, png, background, transparent

image1.png and image2.png are both with transparent background.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img#test").click(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "image2.png");
        });
    });
</script>
<img id="test" src="image1.png">
```

The above code is supposed to replace image1.png with image2.png. But in Internet Explorer 6/7/8 (Compatibility View off), it wont clear image1.png from background but just lay image2.png over image1.png.

How to dynamically remove image1.png from background completely before replacing with image2.png?

**EDIT**

I used the following code in base.css to fix bugs in displaying tranparent .png image in Internet Explorer.

/* Png Ransparent */

.mypng img {

azimuth: expression(

this.pngSet?this.pngSet=true:(this.nodeName == "IMG" && this.src.toLowerCase().indexOf('.png')>-1?(this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = "none",

this.runtimeStyle.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + this.src + "', sizingMethod='image')",

this.src = "/static/images/transparent.gif"):(this.origBg = this.origBg? this.origBg :this.currentStyle.backgroundImage.toString().replace('url("','').replace('")',''),

this.runtimeStyle.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + this.origBg + "', sizingMethod='crop')",

this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = "none")),this.pngSet=true);

}

Is that the cause of this problem?

Comment: There must be more at matter. I can't reproduce this. You're also talking about "background", are you sure that you don't have any CSS which is doing exactly that?

Comment: @BalusC: anything is possible with IE :)

Comment: @Andreas: I tested exactly this code snippet in IE6/7/8 with two different transparent PNG images and it works fine in all (except that the aplha channel isn't present in IE6, but that's another problem).

Comment: @BalusC, i added some code in the page's stylesheets to fix bugs in displaying transparent .png image bugs. Maybe it's the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `$(this).after();` and add a new image after the one you want to substitute; and finally do `$(this).remove();`

Comment: this works but it results in some flickering when switching image.

Answer (score 0):

After replaced .png fix code with [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/), the former code works.